# Disabled pasting and numbers, now can't erase letters in UITextField [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have a UITextField which I disabled the option to paste and write number (letters only), but now, for some reason, I can't erase!

This is my code in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
    var textField1 = UITextField()
        textField1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 30, view.frame.width - 20, 30)
        textField1.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        textField1.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
        textField1.keyboardType = .Default
        textField1.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
        textField1.font = UIFont(name: "MyriadHebrew-Regular", size: 30)
        textField1.textColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 215/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        textField1.tintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 215/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        textField1.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(textField1)
```

This is the not posting function:

```
override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(NSObject.paste(_:)) {
            print("no paste")
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
```

And this is the only letters function:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()) != nil {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should return `true` from `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` when `string` is an empty string.

Comment: @dan I don't get it.. can you code it as an answer please?

Answer (score -1):

When the backspace key is pressed your textfield delegate method is called with the range of the last character in the textfields text string and the replacement string as an empty string.  You are currently returning `false` in this case which prevents the deletion from happening.

You probably want:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   return string.isEmpty || string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()) != nil
}
```

Comment: This is the error I get:
`No '!=' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSCharacterSet'`

Comment: Sorry, missed a `)`.  Fixed now

Comment: First of all - thank you for your help! second, it works, but for some reason the paste option is avaible again and I can't make space as well. Any idea why or how to fix it?